# Tenant Secure Score - Average Comparative Scores data are not available in Graph API

Tags: rest, microsoft-graph-api

From August 7, 2021 onwards, I couldn't retrieve the data for Average Comparative scores in Microsoft Secure Scores via REST API.

REST API used : https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/security/secureScores

Shortend sample Response:

```
{
    "id": "$$$$$$$$$$$$$$",
    "azureTenantId": "$$$$$$$$$$$",
    "activeUserCount": 22,
    "createdDateTime": "2021-09-08T00:00:00Z",
    "currentScore": 27.96,
    "enabledServices": [
        "HasProject",
        "HasVisio",
        "HasAADBasic",
        "HasTeams"
    ],
    "licensedUserCount": 250,
    "maxScore": 79,
    "vendorInformation": {
        "provider": "SecureScore",
        "providerVersion": null,
        "subProvider": null,
        "vendor": "Microsoft"
    },
    ** "averageComparativeScores": [
        {
            "basis": "AllTenants",
            "averageScore": 0,
            "deviceScoreMax": 0,
            "appsScoreMax": 0,
            "infrastructureScoreMax": 0,
            "dataScoreMax": 0,
            "identityScore": 0,
            "deviceScore": 0,
            "appsScore": 0,
            "identityScoreMax": 0,
            "infrastructureScore": 0,
            "dataScore": 0
        },
        {
            "basis": "IndustryTypes",
            "averageScore": 0,
            "deviceScoreMax": 0,
            "appsScoreMax": 0,
            "infrastructureScoreMax": 0,
            "dataScoreMax": 0,
            "identityScore": 0,
            "deviceScore": 0,
            "appsScore": 0,
            "identityScoreMax": 0,
            "infrastructureScore": 0,
            "dataScore": 0
        },
        {
            "basis": "TotalSeats",
            "averageScore": 0,
            "deviceScoreMax": 0,
            "appsScoreMax": 0,
            "infrastructureScoreMax": 0,
            "dataScoreMax": 0,
            "identityScore": 0,
            "deviceScore": 0,
            "appsScore": 0,
            "identityScoreMax": 0,
            "infrastructureScore": 0,
            "dataScore": 0
        }
    ]** ,
    "controlScores": [
        {
            "controlCategory": "Identity",
            "controlName": "AdminMFAV2",
            "description": "Requiring multi-factor authentication (MFA) for all administrative roles makes it harder for attackers to access accounts. Administrative roles have higher permissions than typical users. If any of those accounts are compromised, critical devices and data is open to attack.  ",
            "score": 6.96,
            "implementationStatus": "You have 16 out of 23 users with administrative roles registered and protected with MFA.",
            "controlState": "active",
            "lastSynced": "2021-09-08T00:00:00Z",
            "IsApplicable": "true",
            "count": "7",
            "total": "23",
            "scoreInPercentage": 69.56
        }
```

] }

Is there a bug in this API else I need to use different REST API for fetching these comparative scores?

Thanks in Advance

Regards,

Maerona Wynn

Comment: From the documentation https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/security-list-securescores?view=graph-rest-beta this API doesn't look like it is available in beta anymore, would you try with https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/security/secureScores and see whether the result is the same?

Comment: The result is same in v1.0 version too. 

Shortend sample response:



averageComparativeScores": 
                {
                    "basis": "AllTenants",
                    "averageScore": 0,
                    "appsScoreMax": 0,
                    "appsScore": 0,
                    "infrastructureScoreMax": 0,
                    "identityScoreMax": 0,
                    "deviceScoreMax": 0,
                    "deviceScore": 0,
                    "infrastructureScore": 0,
                    "dataScore": 0,
                    "dataScoreMax": 0}